# How to Get Web Access Panel After Installing NextCloud Server from Snap?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, nextcloud

I'm following a few tutorials to set up my laptop as a Nextcloud server and have just installed NextCloud from a snap package and verified that it is installed properly.

I'm looking to get to the web interface to create an admin account and proceed with the tutorial, but I can't seem to find the `https://IP_OF_SERVER/nextcloud` page. I've tried replacing the `IP_OF_SERVER` with some of the ip addresses from `ip a`, but this doesn't seem to be effective, and worse, this is a local ip address.

How would I access this from my phone when I'm out and not on the network?

How do I get the proper IP address to enter into the browser to create an account, and will this be visible to an android phone not on the Network?

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.01 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

check if localhost is listed in the trusted domains in config.php. If not try adding it. For me trying localhost.local worked (like server.local).